# How to wait for changing different imageviews in android?

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, refresh

I'm using this code to change between different images, but the only image that is visualized is the last one. The TextView "vista_aterrizaje" does not show the expected value in each loop.

I have tried to use invalidate() method before the sleep() one, to try to visualize it in each different loop of the for. But it does not work.

establecerImagen() method is used for changing the imageView.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        cur_aterrizaje = aterrizajes[rand.nextInt(aterrizajes.length)];
        vista_aterrizaje.setText(cur_aterrizaje);
        establecerImagen(cur_aterrizaje);
        vista_aterrizaje.();
        mapa.invalidate();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I think that the problem is in the sleep() method but I don't know how to wait a few seconds after every change of the views in order to visualize every change.

Comment: Try setting the sleep to a longer period like 2000 (2 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Try using CountDownTimer.

```
     // here interval 1000 stands for 1sec, 
    //so onTick() will be called 15 times, each call after 1 sec interval. so you can set your own values as per your need.
        int i=0;
        long interval  = 1000;
        new CountDownTimer((15 * interval), interval){
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {
                            vista_aterrizaje.setText(i+"");
                            establecerImagen(cur_aterrizaje);
                            i++;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                        }
                    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to sleep() is in milliseconds.  So if you want to show each image for 1 second, the parameter should be 1000.

A better way to do it would be like this:

```
handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //display your image here -- it will be displayed after a 1-second delay
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```